# how to convert an index from the list and convert that into an integer

Tags: python

I'm trying to right this code for school and it says

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Here is my code

```py
val = (int)(input)("Enter your Age: ")
print(val)
if (val) > 10:
    print('your in double digits')
else:
    print('You are in the single digits
```

Comment: You should use `val = int(input("Enter your Age: "))`

Comment: this is not how to cast in python... should be: `val = int(input("Enter your Age: "))`.

Answer (score 0):

you should change to

```
val = int(input("Enter your Age: "))
print(val)
if (val) > 10:
    print('your in double digits')
else:
    print('You are in the single digits
```